# Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm working on an e-commerce web app using Laravel and Vuejs. I chose Stripe's API to accept and manage payments.
In my Vue component, which contains the payment form, and before making it visible(I'm using a multi-step form), I send a post request to my payments store controller function to 'initialize' Stripe and get the clientSecret variable. As follows:

```
 axios
        .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/payments', {
            headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            'total': this.total,
            'mode_payment': this.mode_payment
        })
```

This is how the store function looks like in my PaymentController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $payment = new Payment; 

    $payment->montant_payment = $request->total;
    $payment->mode = $request->mode_payment;
    $payment->date_payment = Carbon::now();
    $payment->statut_payment = false;       
    $payment->save();

    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $intent = PaymentIntent::create([
      'amount' => $payment->montant_payment,
      'currency' => 'usd',
    ]);

   
    $clientSecret = Arr::get($intent, 'client_secret');
    $amount = $payment->montant_payment;

    return response()->json($clientSecret);        
}
```

As you can see, the store function sends back a JSON response containing the clientSecret variable. This response is then captured by the same Vue component discussed above.

This is how the Vue component captures the response:

```
.then((response) => {
    this.clientSecret = response.data;
    var stripe = 
    Stripe('pk_test_51JL3DSLJetNHxQ3207t13nuwhCB1KPvUJJshapsOQATnZn79vA4wK3p9Hf2yi2uUXfXXWdAtLZGRepfJGvRnd7oI006Kw6rFTC');
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var style = {
    base: {
        color: "#32325d",
    }
    };

    this.card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
    this.card.mount("#card-element");
    this.card.on('change', ({error}) => {
    let displayError = document.getElementById('card-error');
    if (error) {
        displayError.classList.add('alert', 'alert-warning');
        displayError.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
        displayError.classList.remove('alert', 'alert-warning');
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        // If the client secret was rendered server-side as a data-secret attribute
        // on the <form> element, you can retrieve it here by calling `form.dataset.secret`
        stripe.confirmCardPayment(String(this.clientSecret), {
            payment_method: {
                card: this.card,
                billing_details: {
                    name: "testan testo"
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
            // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
            console.log(result.error.message);
            } 
            else {
            // The payment has been processed!
                if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                    console.log(result.paymentIntent);
                    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment-success/';
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Using Vue web dev tools I checked that the clientSecret variable has been successfully passed from the laravel store controller function to the payment Vue component, thanks to the execution of the commmand : `this.clientSecret = response.data;`.

However, when clicking the pay button, I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}.
    at X ((index):1)
    at Q ((index):1)
    at lo ((index):1)
    at (index):1
    at (index):1
    at e.<anonymous> ((index):1)
    at e.confirmCardPayment ((index):1)
    at HTMLFormElement.eval (ComLivPay.vue?5598:339)
```

I guess the problem then is in the next portion of code:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(String(this.clientSecret), {
    payment_method: {
        card: this.card,
        billing_details: {
            name: "testan testo"
        }
    }
})
```

**EDIT:**

Since the problem seems to arise from the string form of the `this.clientSecret` variable. Here's how it looks like in Vue dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that server-side in PHP you do get the `client_secret` populated properly? If so, have you confirmed that your JS code properly reads and deserializes that JSON response you get from the AJAX request? And then if so, have you checked what you get from `response.data` which you don't seem to explicitly access. Did you try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))` for example? It seems like you are missing debugging steps and assume `this.clientSecret` is set when it's not.

Comment: @koopajah
I checked all of that and the `this.clientSecret` is properly set. I already said that I checked its value using Vue's available dev tools in Chrome.

Comment: You hint at this but I am not convinced that you logged the exact value of `this.clientSecret` before calling `confirmCardPayment()` in this case. That's what I'd recommend double checking and it's likely not set the way you think it is